# LFS Chapter 6.20 Ncurses install error

Tags: installation, ncurses, linux-from-scratch

I've been going step by step until midnight, then I turned off the Laptop (Standby) - i've **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** as OS. When I woke up I wanted to continue, so I started my laptop again, but the screen kept black. I shut it down, and started it.

I had to mount everything, so I executed this:

```
# mount -v -t ext4 /dev/sda3 $LFS
# rm /tools
# ln -sv $LFS/tools /
# chroot "$LFS" /tools/bin/env -i \
     HOME=/root                  \
     TERM="$TERM"                \
     PS1='\u:\w\$ '              \
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin \
     /tools/bin/bash --login +h
```

When I enter to `/source/ncurses-5.9/` and execute `./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --with-shared --without-debug --enable-pc-files --enable-widec` it gives me back:

```
checking for egrep... grep -E
Configuring NCURSES 5.9 ABI 5 (Sun Apr 26 07:23:00 UTC 2015)
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configuring for linux-gnu
checking for prefix... /usr
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for executable suffix... 
checking for object suffix... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking version of gcc... 4.9.2
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for POSIXized ISC... no
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... -DCC_HAS_PROTOS
checking for ldconfig... /sbin/ldconfig
checking if you want to ensure bool is consistent with C++... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++... /usr/bin/g++
checking version of g++... 4.9.2
checking if you want to build C++ binding and demo... yes
checking if you want to build with Ada95... yes
checking if you want to install manpages... yes
checking if you want to build programs such as tic... yes
checking if you want to build test-programs... yes
checking if you wish to install curses.h... yes
checking for mawk... no
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for egrep... (cached) grep -E
checking for a BSD compatible install... /tools/bin/install -c
checking for tdlint... no
checking for lint... no
checking for alint... no
checking for splint... no
checking for lclint... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking if ln -s -f options work... yes
checking for long file names... yes
checking if you want to use pkg-config... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking if we should install .pc files for /usr/bin/pkg-config... yes
checking if we should assume mixed-case filenames... auto
checking if filesystem supports mixed-case filenames... yes
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... yes
checking for exctags... no
checking for ctags... no
checking for exetags... no
checking for etags... no
checking for ctags... no
checking for etags... no
checking for makeflags variable... 
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ld... ld
checking for ar... ar
checking for ar... (cached) ar
checking for options to update archives... -curv
checking if you have specified an install-prefix... 
checking if libtool -version-number should be used... yes
checking if you want to build libraries with libtool... no
checking if you want to build shared libraries... yes
checking if you want to build static libraries... yes
checking if you want to build debug libraries... no
checking if you want to build profiling libraries... no
checking for specified models...  shared normal
checking for default model... shared
checking if you want to build a separate terminfo library... no
checking if you want to build a separate tic library... no
checking if you want to link with the GPM mouse library... maybe
checking for gpm.h... no
checking for default loader flags... 
checking if rpath option should be used... no
checking if shared libraries should be relinked during install... yes
checking for an rpath option... -Wl,-rpath,
checking if release/abi version should be used for shared libs... auto
checking which gcc option to use... -fPIC
checking if rpath-hack should be disabled... no
checking for updated LDFLAGS... maybe
checking for ldd... ldd
checking if you wish to install ncurses overwriting curses... yes
checking if external terminfo-database is used... yes
checking which terminfo source-file will be installed... ${top_srcdir}/misc/terminfo.src
checking whether to use hashed database instead of directory/tree... no
checking for list of fallback descriptions... 
checking if you want modern xterm or antique... xterm-new
checking for list of terminfo directories... /usr/share/terminfo
checking for default terminfo directory... /usr/share/terminfo
checking if big-core option selected... yes
checking if big-strings option selected... yes
checking if you want termcap-fallback support... no
checking if ~/.terminfo is wanted... yes
checking if you want to use restricted environment when running as root... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for unlink... yes
checking if link/symlink functions work...  link symlink
checking if tic should use symbolic links... no
checking if tic should use hard links... yes
checking if you want broken-linker support code... no
checking if tputs should process BSD-style prefix padding... no
checking if we must define _GNU_SOURCE... yes
checking if SIGWINCH is defined... yes
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes
checking if you want wide-character code... yes
checking if we must define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED... no
checking for putwc... yes
checking for btowc... yes
checking for wctob... yes
checking for mbtowc... yes
checking for wctomb... yes
checking for mblen... yes
checking for mbrlen... yes
checking for mbrtowc... yes
checking for wcsrtombs... yes
checking for mbsrtowcs... yes
checking for wcstombs... yes
checking for mbstowcs... yes
checking if we must include wchar.h to declare mbstate_t... yes
checking if we must include wchar.h to declare wchar_t... no
checking if we must include wchar.h to declare wint_t... yes
checking whether to enable _LP64 definition in curses.h... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for _LARGE_FILES value needed for large files... no
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking for fseeko... yes
checking whether to use struct dirent64... no
checking if you want tparm not to use X/Open fixed-parameter list... yes
checking for type of bool... auto
checking for alternate terminal capabilities file... Caps
checking for type of chtype... auto
checking for type of ospeed... short
checking for type of mmask_t... auto
checking for size CCHARW_MAX... 5
checking if RCS identifiers should be compiled-in... no
checking format of man-pages... normal
checking for manpage renaming... no
checking if manpage aliases will be installed... yes
checking if manpage symlinks should be used... yes
checking for manpage tbl... no
checking if you want to build with function extensions... yes
checking if you want to build with experimental SCREEN extensions... no
checking if you want to build with experimental terminal-driver... no
checking for extended use of const keyword... no
checking if you want to use extended colors... no
checking if you want to use extended mouse encoding... no
checking if you want $NCURSES_NO_PADDING code... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for signed char... yes
checking size of signed char... 1
checking if you want to use signed Boolean array in term.h... no
checking if you want SIGWINCH handler... yes
checking if you want user-definable terminal capabilities like termcap... yes
checking if you want all development code... no
checking if you want hard-tabs code... no
checking if you want limited support for xmc... no
checking if you do not want to assume colors are white-on-black... yes
checking if you want hashmap scrolling-optimization code... yes
checking if you want colorfgbg code... no
checking if you want interop bindings... no
checking if you want to link with the pthread library... no
checking if you want experimental reentrant code... no
checking if you want experimental safe-sprintf code... no
checking if you want experimental wgetch-events code... no
checking if you want to display full commands during build... yes
checking if you want to see compiler warnings... 
configure: checking for gcc __attribute__ directives...
... scanf
... printf
... unused
... noreturn
checking if you want to enable runtime assertions... no
checking if you want to use dmalloc for testing... no
checking if you want to use dbmalloc for testing... no
checking if you want to use valgrind for testing... no
checking if you want to perform memory-leak testing... no
checking whether to add trace feature to all models... no
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking if -lm needed for math functions... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for opendir in -ldir... no
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for regcomp... yes
checking for regular-expression headers... regex.h
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for math.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/bsdtypes.h... no
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking for ttyent.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking if sys/time.h works with sys/select.h... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking if gcc supports options to tune inlining... yes
checking for signal global datatype... volatile sig_atomic_t
checking for type of chtype... int
checking if unsigned literals are legal... yes
checking if external errno is declared... yes
checking if external errno exists... no
checking if data-only library module links... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for getegid... yes
checking for geteuid... yes
checking for getttynam... yes
checking for issetugid... no
checking for poll... yes
checking for remove... (cached) yes
checking for select... yes
checking for setbuf... yes
checking for setbuffer... yes
checking for setvbuf... yes
checking for sigaction... yes
checking for sigvec... no
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for tcgetpgrp... yes
checking for times... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for isascii... yes
checking whether sigaction needs _POSIX_SOURCE... no
checking if nanosleep really works... yes
checking for termio.h... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking whether termios.h needs _POSIX_SOURCE... no
checking for tcgetattr... yes
checking for vsscanf function or workaround... vsscanf
checking for working mkstemp... yes
checking whether setvbuf arguments are reversed... no
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for type sigaction_t... no
checking declaration of size-change... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking if poll really works... yes
checking for va_copy... yes
checking for __va_copy... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... (cached) yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for openpty in -lutil... yes
checking for openpty header... pty.h
checking if we should include stdbool.h... yes
checking for builtin bool type... no
checking for library stdc++... no
checking whether /usr/bin/g++ understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /usr/bin/g++ -E
checking for iostream... yes
checking for typeinfo... yes
checking if iostream uses std-namespace... yes
checking if we should include stdbool.h... (cached) yes
checking for builtin bool type... yes
checking for size of bool... unsigned char
checking for special defines needed for etip.h... MATH_H 
checking if /usr/bin/g++ accepts parameter initialization... no
checking if /usr/bin/g++ accepts static_cast... yes
checking for gnatmake... no
checking for library subsets... ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs
checking default library suffix... w
checking default library-dependency suffix... w.so
checking default object directory... obj_s
checking c++ library-dependency suffix... w.a
checking where we will install curses.h... ${prefix}/include
checking for src modules... ncurses progs panel menu form
checking for tic... /tools/bin/tic
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating include/MKterm.h.awk
config.status: creating include/curses.head
config.status: creating include/ncurses_dll.h
config.status: creating include/termcap.h
config.status: creating include/unctrl.h
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating include/Makefile
config.status: creating ncurses/Makefile
config.status: creating progs/Makefile
config.status: creating panel/Makefile
config.status: creating menu/Makefile
config.status: creating form/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating misc/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/Makefile
config.status: creating Ada95/gen/adacursesw-config
config.status: creating man/adacursesw-config.1
config.status: creating misc/run_tic.sh
config.status: creating misc/ncurses-config
config.status: creating man/ncursesw5-config.1
config.status: creating misc/gen-pkgconfig
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating include/ncurses_cfg.h
config.status: include/ncurses_cfg.h is unchanged
Appending rules for shared model (ncurses: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (ncurses: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for shared model (progs: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (progs: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for shared model (panel: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (panel: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for shared model (menu: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (menu: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for shared model (form: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (form: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for shared model (test: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (test: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for shared model (c++: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
Appending rules for normal model (c++: ticlib+termlib+ext_tinfo+base+widechar+ext_funcs)
creating headers.sh
./configure: line 21016: 27277 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${MAKE:-make} preinstall
```

And when I try to run `make`, it just says:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**How can I fix that? Or do you need more information?**

Answer (score 1):

From the information, no it is not possible to answer the question.

At that point, the configure script simply runs "make" with a rule that runs a series of `echo` commands.  There are no other programs involved than `sh`, `make` and `echo` (which you can see by viewing the generated `Makefile` and looking for `preinstall`.  You should have seen this:

```
** Configuration summary for NCURSES 5.9 20110404:

     extended funcs: yes
     xterm terminfo: xterm-new

      bin directory: /usr/bin
      lib directory: /usr/lib
  include directory: /usr/include
      man directory: /usr/share/man
 terminfo directory: /usr/share/terminfo
```

Whatever problem is there, appears unrelated to ncurses.

I would be tempted to restart the install, supposing that something went amiss when suspending and resuming.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. I backed it up in the end of chapter 5. I will begin from there again.

Comment: But I will first try to restart, because since I forced it to shut down, the Linux Kernel throws everytime an error